# Angle quotes with csquotes and T2A encoding

Tags: font-encodings, cyrillic, csquotes

I'd like to get this:

[image: result I want]

I can easily get this via `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and the use of `\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}`

But for Russian I need `[T2A]{fontenc}` and the inner quotes get messed up. It then looks like this:

[image: result as I don't want it]

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc} % T2A messes up inner quotes
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,german]{babel}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

Someone said: \enquote{The other one told me: \enquote{Don't bother!}}

\end{document}
```

I already tried it with:
`\usepackage[style=russian]{csquotes}`
and other settings I don't remember ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\guilsinglright}{T1}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\guilsinglleft}{T1}
```

to your preamble.

Btw: If your main language is german you should load T1 as the last encoding so that it is active at the start of the document.

```
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: Works as intended! Thank You. About switching encoding order: Already tried that before. With T1 at second position I run into errors at the first line with Cyrillic letters.

Comment: Well you natually need to switch to T2A when you start to write russian text. Doesn't \selectlanguage{russian} does it automatically?

Comment: To be frank, I never used selectlanguage{german} when using T2A. It just works for German as well, as it seems. According to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Cyrillic_script : "Babel will take care of switching to the appropriate font encoding when a different language is selected within the document." But this maybe involves \selectlanguage ??